# передать переменную с помощью $_SESSION на другую страницу

Tags: php, сессия

есть ссылка: *http://www.cr.com/act.php?key=YWFAYWEuYWE*

в файле *act.php* следующий код:

```
<?php
    $key = $_GET['key'];
    $_SESSION['key'] = $key;
    header("location: http://cr.com/error/");
?>
```

код страницы *error*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h4>
                <?php 
                    if($_SESSION['key'] != "")
                    {
                        echo $_SESSION['key'];
                    }
                ?>
            </h4>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

я при клике на ссылку пытаюсь прочитать переменную `key` с помощью `$_GET`, запоминаю его в `$_SESSION`, перехожу на страницу error и вывожу там.

НО при клике на ссылку меня перекидывает на пустую страницу error.
Думал не срабатывает `$_GET`

Сделал так, код файла *act.php* поменял на:

```
<?php
    $key = $_GET['key'];
    $_SESSION['key'] = $key;

    echo $_SESSION['key'];
?>
```

В итоге при клике на ссылку я остаюсь на странице *act.php*, а `echo $_SESSION['key'];` срабатывает нормально и выводит `YWFAYWEuYWE`.

Почему значение `$_SESSION['key']` не выводится на странице *error*?

Comment: html код страницы error и php код из act.php находятся в разных файлах

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.session-start.php

Comment: сюда почему то не вставилось, я делаю session_start(); в начале файла act.php. Вы же это имели ввиду?

Comment: в начале страницы error перед <!DOCTYPE html> делаю <?php
 session_start();
 header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
?>

Comment: Перенесите содержимое комментариев в текст ответа. Посмотрите в логи и опубликуйте что в пишется в то время когда вы делаете запрос

Comment: все, спасибо, я поправил баг. проблема заключалось в том, что сессии не передавались на другую страницу..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что не передавались сессии на другую страницу!

Сессии, как оказалось, не передаются, если в редиректе указан абсолютный адрес:

```
header("location: http://cr.com/error/");
```

Поменял на:

```
header("location: /error/");
```

и все, сессии передаются, все работает как надо :)

Answer (score 1):

Потому что сессию проверять надо прежде, чем выполнять редирект:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    $key = $_GET['key'];
    $_SESSION['key'] = $key;

    if ($_SESSION['key'] == "") {
        header("location: http://cr.com/error/");
    }

?>
```

Comment: не, я хотел в файле act.php прочитать значение key ($key = $_GET['key'];), потом передать его на страницу error и вывести там. Делаю (echo $_SESSION['key']) на странице act.php все нормально выводит, а на странице error ничего не выводится.